# Error: unable to use groupby to summarize table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sum the elements in a df by column using Pandas, and I am obtaining an error. Here is the script
Thank you very much!

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Book1.csv']))
print(df)
df.groupby(['x']).sum()
```

```
         x;y
0  guazaba;1
1  guazaba;1
2  guazaba;1
3     pera;1

 

860                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    861             else:
--> 862                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    863         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    864             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Default separator for csv is `,`, you separator is `;`, so you should define it explicitly

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Book1.csv']), sep=';')
```